# KDB: select rows based on value in one column being contained in the list of another column

Tags: kdb

very simple, silly question.  Consider the following table:

```
tt:([]Id:`6`7`12 ;sym:`A`B`C;symlist:((`A`B`M);(`X`Y`Z);(`H`F`C)))

Id  sym symlist
---------------
6   A   `A`B`M
7   B   `X`Y`Z
12  C   `H`F`C
```

I would like to select all rows in tt where the element in sym is contained in the list symlist.  In this case, it means just the first and third rows.  However, the following query gives me a type error.

```
select from tt where sym in symlist
(`type)
```

Whats the proper way to do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `'` (each-both) adverb, so that they "pair up" so to speak. Recall that `sym` is just list, and `symlist` is a list of lists. You want to check each element in `sym` with the respective sub-list in `symlist`. You do this by telling it to "pair up".

```
q)tt:([]id:6712; sym:`A`B`C; symlist:(`A`B`M;`X`Y`Z;`H`F`C))
q)select from tt where sym in'symlist
id   sym symlist
----------------
6712 A   A B M  
6712 C   H F C
```

It's not entirely clear to me why your query results in a type error, so I'd be interested in hearing other people's responses.

```
q)select from tt where sym in symlist
'type
in
`A`B`C
(`A`B`M;`X`Y`Z;`H`F`C)
q)select from tt where {x in y}[sym;symlist]
id sym symlist
--------------
```

Answer (score 1):

In reponse to JPCs answer (couldn't format this as a comment)....

Type error possibly caused by applying "where" to a scalar boolean

```
q)(`a`b`c) in (`a`g`b;`u`i`o;`g`c`t)
0b
q)where (`a`b`c) in (`a`g`b;`u`i`o;`g`c`t)
'type
```

Also, the reason the {x in y} lambda doesn't cause the error is because the "in" is obscured and is not visible to the parser (parser doesn't look inside lambdas)

```
q)0N!parse"select from tt where {x in y}[sym;symlist]";
(?;`tt;,,({x in y};`sym;`symlist);0b;())
```

Whereas the parser can "see" the "in" in the first case

```
q)0N!parse"select from tt where sym in symlist";
(?;`tt;,,(in;`sym;`symlist);0b;())
```

I'm guessing the parser tries to do some optimisations when it sees the "in"

Comment: Your point on optimizations makes sense to me. The obscuring less so, because in the following it has access to see the `in` `q)select from tt where tt[\`sym] in tt[\`symlist]` and this doesn't result in a type error